# Image is Chrome Extension not shown

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I would like to create a Chrome extension, where I append stars to a webpage. I have created the manifest.json, content.js and style.css files. I can see the place of the image, but it is not shown. I have spent 5-6 hours debugging it, but nothing seems to work.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Random Stars",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Randomly assigns stars",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all-urls>"
      ],
      "css": [
        "style.css"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "star.png"
      ],
      "matches": [ "<all-urls>" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

content.js:

```
if (window.location.hostname === "<url>") {
  const companyNames = document.querySelectorAll('<selector>');

  companyNames.forEach(companyName => {
    const stars = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    const starDiv = document.createElement('div');
    starDiv.classList.add('company-stars');
    // starDiv.style.backgroundImage = chrome.runtime.getURL("star.png");
    starDiv.style.width = `${stars * 20}px`;
    companyName.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', starDiv);
  });
}
```

style.css:

```
.company-stars {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("star.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
```

I can see that stars are generated because the place of the image is there and the length of each div is different, but the image is not shown at all.

What I tried so far:

- I was able to open the image in Chrome in an HTML file
- I tried to transform styles from `style.css` to `content.js`, but it did not help
- Use only the `display` property of the CSS, but it did not help either
- I tried to get rid of the image URL from CSS and JS files (separately) - if I got rid of it in CSS, the place of the image wasn't there while it was when commenting out the background-img in the JS file
- I made sure `star.png` is in the same folder as `content.js`, `manifest.json` and `style.css`
- I also receive `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag` but I don't think that is the issue here

If someone has experience with this, could you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: You need to use `chrome.runtime.getURL` in `content.js`.

Comment: Add `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/` before star.png in style.css. Another potential problem may be that the site adds the elements dynamically, in which case you'll need to use MutationObserver in content.js.

Comment: BTW there's a typo: `all-urls` should be `all_urls` in both places.

Comment: @wOxxOm your solution of adding the `chrome-extension` solved my issue, thank you!